# How to retrieve the exact HTML as in a browser

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, pyqt

I'm using a Python script to render web pages and retrieve their HTML's. It works fine with most of the pages, but with some of them the HTML retrieved is incomplete. And I don't quite understand why. This is the script I'm using to scrap this page, for some reason, the link to every product is not in the HTML:

Link: http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos-c29016.html

Python script:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4 import QtNetwork
from PyQt4 import QtCore

url = sys.argv[1]
path = sys.argv[2]

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest() 
    self.request.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(url)) 
    self.request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", QtCore.QByteArray ("es ,*"))
    self.mainFrame().load(self.request)
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

r = Render(url)  
result = r.frame.toHtml()

html_file = open(path, "w")
html_file.write("%s" % result.encode("utf-8"))
html_file.close()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code was taken from here: https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/

Am I missing something? What are the limitations of this framework?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Perhaps the page uses javascript to dynamically load other parts of the page, or modify the DOM. In other words, what you get from the server in HTML form isn't necessarily what you get after javascript runs. Your PHP isn't running any javascript.

Comment: you need a browser to get the same page markup as a browser will realize.

Comment: @sethflowers *"Your PHP isn't running any javascript."* are you sure, have you checked the link the OP provides as reference ?

Comment: @Ilya - I haven't checked the page. I don't click links when I don't recognize the domain. I was just guessing :).

Comment: @sethflowers The Web kit library is supposed to render pages when there's JS code. And most of the time this works well, but not with the link I provided.

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham just the link of every product.

Comment: @cuoka you should use PyQt5 rather than PyQt4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want headless browsing you can combine [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) with [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), the following gets all the source:

```
url = "http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos-c29016.html"
from selenium import webdriver

dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
dr.get(url)

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(dr, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "grid_itemContainer"))
)
```

Just using selenium without the `WebDriverWait` did not always return the full source, adding the wait until the a tags with the *grid_itemContainer* class were visible makes sure the html has been generated, the xpath below returns all your links:

```
print([a.get_attribute('href') for a in dr.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='grid_itemContainer']")])

[u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-detalle-crochet-pechera-c29016p100064004.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-bordado-escote-pico-c29016p100123006.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-manga-larga-espalda-abierta-c29016p100147503.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-hombros-descubiertos-beads-c29016p100182001.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-jacquard-capa-c29016p100255505.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-vaquero-eyelets-c29016p100336010.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-liso-oversized-c29016p100289013.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-liso-oversized-c29016p100289013.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-camisero-oversized-c29016p100036616.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-pico-c29016p100166506.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-estampado-rayas-c29016p100234507.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-manga-corta-liso-c29016p100262008.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-largo-cuello-halter-liso-c29016p100036162.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-capa-jacquard-%C3%A9tnico-c29016p100259002.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-largo-cuello-halter-rayas-c29016p100036161.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-capa-jacquard-tri%C3%A1ngulo-c29016p100255506.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-marinero-escote-bardot-c29016p100259003.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-rayas-escote-espalda-c29016p100262007.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cruzado-c29016p100216013.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-flores-canes%C3%BA-bordado-c29016p100203011.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-bordados-c29016p100037160.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-flores-volante-c29016p100216014.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-lencero-c29016p100104515.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuadros-detalle-encaje-c29016p100216016.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-drapeado-abertura-bajo-c29016p100129011.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-drapeado-abertura-bajo-c29016p100129011.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-vaquero-bolsillo-plastr%C3%B3n-c29016p100036822.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-rayas-bajo-desigual-c29016p100123010.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-camisero-vaquero-c29016p100036575.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-midi-estampado-rayas-c29016p100189011.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-midi-rayas-manga-3-4-c29016p100149507.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-midi-canal%C3%A9-ajustado-c29016p100149508.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-estampado-bolsillos-c29016p100212503.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-corte-evas%C3%A9-bolsillos-c29016p100189012.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-vaquero-camisero-cuadros-c29016p100036624.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/pichi-vaquero-c29016p100073526.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-estampado-geom%C3%A9trico-cuello-halter-c29016p100037021.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-perkins-manga-larga-c29016p100036882.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-perkins-manga-larga-c29016p100036882.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-perkins-manga-larga-c29016p100036882.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-perkins-manga-larga-c29016p100036882.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-jacquard-evas%C3%A9-c29016p100037207.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cr%C3%AApe-evas%C3%A9-estampado-flores-manga-3-4-c29016p100036932.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cr%C3%AApe-evas%C3%A9-estampado-flores-manga-3-4-c29016p100037280.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-perkins-parche-c29016p100037464.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cr%C3%AApe-evas%C3%A9-liso-manga-3-4-c29016p100036930.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cr%C3%AApe-evas%C3%A9-liso-manga-3-4-c29016p100036930.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-alto-liso-c29016p100037156.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-alto-estampado-flores-c29016p100036921.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-cuello-alto-estampado-corbatero-c29016p100037155.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-largo-manga-sisa-c29016p100170011.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-largo-manga-sisa-rayas-c29016p100170012.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-manga-acampanada-c29016p100149506.html', u'http://www.pullandbear.com/es/es/mujer/vestidos/vestido-punto-espalda-abierta-c29016p100195504.html']
```

If you want to write the source:

```
with open("out.html", "w") as f:
       f.write(dr.page_source)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to write the result into a file? Because I'm parsing the HTML using Jsoup. I just need the HTML completely rendered.

Comment: @cuoka, yes,  just write the `dr.page_source`. You can do all the parsing with selenium though through various different methods

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use http://ghost-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ for this case. It's loads web page like real browser and run JavaScript.
Also you can try PhantomJS for example, but it written on nodeJS.

Comment: Is this WebKit more powerful that the one I'm using?

Comment: *"Also you can try PhantomJS for example, but it written on nodeJS."* No PhantomJS is written with Qt5.