# Why Scrapy cannot find href here?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get several hrefs that are in html blocks like this one (sorry for formatting but I guess you need everything):

```
<li class="evt-click" data-tab="yo" data-public="yoyo" data-tracking="1" data-tracking-tag="yo_name" data-tracking-params="{'type': 'yo'}" href="/the/url/i/want">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Yo</a>
</li>
```

My scrapy crawling is able to get the `li` elements as `elmts` I want but then when I am trying `elmts.xpath('@href')`, no link is returned.

I don't get it but I am 2 weeks old with Scrapy !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the *hrefs* from the *li's* with the class *evt-click* you can use the following xpath:

```
xpath('//li[@class="evt-click"]/@href'))
```

In your own example you need:

```
 xpath("./@href")
```

The reason neither work is because what you are looking for does not exist in the html in the link you provided, there are 11 `li class="evt-click"` and none contain any href bar the js inside the a tag:

[image]

You can use [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to allow the page to render fully to get the dynamically generated data, you need to install it as per the link instructions:

Add to setting.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware': 725,
}
```

Start a docker instance:

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash:
```

Then this is enough to get the data you want:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "deez"
    start_urls = ["http://www.deezer.com/profile/154723101"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                    'endpoint': 'render.html',
                    'args': {'wait': 1}
                }
            })

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.xpath("//li[@class='evt-click']").extract())
```

Output:

```
$ scrapy crawl deez
.............................
2016-03-20 23:01:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
[u'/profile/154723101/loved', u'/profile/154723101/playlists', u'/profile/154723101/albums', u'/profile/154723101/artists', u'/profile/154723101/radios', u'/profile/154723101/following', u'/profile/154723101/followers']
```

[selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070541/how-to-retrieve-the-exact-html-as-in-a-browser/36072017#36072017) is also another option.

Comment: I tried it as well but it didn't return anything. I also tried xpath('//@href') but I only got the javascript:void(0) texts without anything else.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Do you want all the `evt-click's` or just the one particular? Actually there are no hrefs bar the javascript inside the a tag in any li with the class evt-click

Comment: Nor  does `{'type': 'yo'}` exist in the html

Comment: The (./@href) suggestion doesn't work as well. I could basically take one in particular scrap and do the same thing for all the ones I want. But having all the hrefs from all evt-clicks is the clean way I guess. If I don't find a way to do it I will probably directly fill with the urls I want

Comment: @baptiste, there is no html matching what you have in your question, have you looked at the page source? What are you actually trying to pull from the page?

Comment: Well at the link when I press F12 I got exactly what I sent. Let me send you the img link.

Comment: Yep but that is dynmically generated, to see what scrapy sees use view source.

Comment: This is where my newby me comes in. I am not a web developper at all but more an embedded C one. I will check it then. Thanks

Comment: You can use scrapy splash to render the page, https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash that will allow the content to load, I will add an example in a minute after I verify it works, if not we will probably need selenium

Comment: As you look at the page itself, what are you trying to pull?

Comment: I want all the links corresponding to the different types of music a profile has like "Loved tracks", "Playlists", "Albums", "Artists". Then following these links I want to have a list of everything ("Loved tracks" -> list of tracks names...). That's why this is not a big deal to not be able to get the links as I can just use them raw in my code with "/loved", "/playlists"... at the end of my www.deezer.com/profile/154723101 profile. But if each list of tracks is dynamically generated like you told me, I will have the same issue.

Comment: Just a last question: how do you get the static source code of a page? I always thought the F12 key was enough

Comment: F12 opens the developer console which sees what you see, right clicking  then choosing view page source shows you what scrapy actually sees.

Comment: Ok. So it seems I won't have the same issue if I use raw URLs to get what I want. I will do that and hoping they won't change them soon. Thanks for your help & time !

Comment: No worries, I added an example of using *scrapy-splash* to render the page that will get the data for you